# Visual Studio Mac navigation to symbols not working

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I've reinstalled Visual Studio Mac, deleted all bin and obj folders, cleaned and rebuilt my solution.

But I can't navigate to symbols. It says...

> Cannot navigate to the symbol under the claret.

Any ideas? Is there a stash of VS data somewhere that I can delete with extreme prejudice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already searched your hard disk with "Visual Studio" or something? Maybe there're some files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One project appeared twice in the solution file. I removed one of the references.